# Execute a console program, write to standard input and read result with pipe

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, pipe

I need to execute my console program, write some value to the standard input and read the result with pipe. I tried to implement it. This code works perfectly. But I think there are other easier ways to implement it. Do you have any ideas?

```
pid_t pid = fork();
std::string output_data;
if(pid < 0)
{
    printf("Error\n");
}
else if(!pid)
{
    FILE* process = popen(program.c_str(), "r");
    char temp_data[128];
    if(process)
    {
        while(fgets(temp_data, sizeof(temp_data), process))
        {
            output_data.append(temp_data);
        }
    }
    pclose(process);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    FILE* process = popen(program.c_str(), "w");
    std::string output_data;
    char temp_data[128];
    if(process)
    {
        fwrite("5", 1, sizeof(int), process);
    }
    pclose(process);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code will run 4 processes: One process forks into 2, and then each of them forks using popen(). popen() will not only create a pipe but also a child process connected through that pipe, thus each of the 2 processes calling popen() will create a child process.

You should decide how to go: Either let popen() do all the work, but then don't use fork(), or let [pipe()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html) create the pipe yourself and use fork() - that is what my code below does.

There is still one big difference: popen() will not only fork, but also, in the child, execute another program. My example stays in the same executable. If you want to execute another program in the child, then popen() can be quite useful, but then you should not use fork().

```
int fsd[2]; // write to fds[1], read from fds[0]
pipe(fds);  // creates the pipe with read+write file descriptors in fds
id_t pid = fork();
std::string output_data;
if(pid < 0)
{
    printf("Error\n");
}
else if(!pid)
{
    close(fds[1]); // else we'll never detect end of input
    FILE* process = fdopen(fds[0], "r");
    char temp_data[128];
    if(process)
    {
        while(fgets(temp_data, sizeof(temp_data), process))
        {
            output_data.append(temp_data);
        }
    }
    pclose(process);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    close(fds[0]); // just to clean up
    FILE* process = fdopen(fds[1], "w");
    std::string output_data;
    char temp_data[128];
    if(process)
    {
        fprintf(process, "5\n"); // your fwrite("5",...) worked by luck only
    }
    pclose(process);
}
```

Finally, if you want your process to launch **another** executable, write to that excutable and then read from it, you need to do this:

Create 2 pipes, one used to write from the parent to child and one to write back from child to parent, and then do some magic to re-assign the file descriptors:

```
int p2c[2]; pipe(p2c); // parent to child
int c2p[2]; pipe(c2p); // child to parent
if(fork()) { // parent -  I ignore error checks here
    close(p2c[0]); // the child reads from that
    close(c2p[1]); // the child writes to that
    FILE * f_w = fdopen(p2c[1],"w");
    ... write some data to the child using f_w ...
    fclose(f_w);
    FILE * f_r = fdopen(c2p[0],"r");
    ... read some data from the child using f_r ...
    fclose(f_r);
    wait(0); // just to avoid a zombie
} else { // in the child, change stdin and stdout
    close(p2c[1]); close(0); dup(p2c[0]); close(p2c[0]);
    close(c2p[0]); close(1); dup(c2p[1]); close(c2p[1]);
    ... now use execv or something similar to run the other executable
}
```